# Which one is a generally better concept: store selected item or only its key (aka id)?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, knockout.js, viewmodel

I have a quite big dilemma nowadays about general viewmodel design concepts. I mean general, like it's not exactly bound to a given language or environment: I had same dilemma when I wrote viewmodels for Winforms, WPF or KnockoutJS.

As a simplified use case, consider that I have a view where I have to select a country and a city from two select boxes. Both are represented in the database with a unique ID, a Name, and some other relevant information like - let's say - Population. Now imagine that I have to present a textual form of the currently selected data in for example the view's heading like "You've selected London, England". Now here is my two alternatives for creating a viewmodel, I will try to enumerate the pros/contras which I'm already thinking of below each version. The code is written in kind of pseudo way to be as generic as possible.

```
class RegionModel {
  ID: number;
  Name: string;
  Population: number;
}
```

### **Version 1: Storing the selected object.**

```
class MainView {
  SelectedCountry: RegionModel;
  SelectedCity: RegionModel;

  SelectionInfo: string; // computed, should return the "You've selected ...." caption

  Countries: List<RegionModel>; // datasource for country select
  Cities: List<RegionModel> // datasource for city select
}
```

**Pros:**

- Straightforward and easy to understand due to that the selected
  item's type is the same as the selectable items' type.
- Easy to compute such infos like "You've selected ..." because all the
  members    of the currently selected item are present directly.

**Cons:**

- It holds more information than usually a consumer API needs. Usually
  it needs only the ID.
- If it's used in a client-side app, the whole selected object will be
  returned to the server, consuming bandwidth.
- If the consumer API needs only ID's (like in most cases), I have to
  solve some kind of conversion before I pass it. In a web app probably
  during serialization to JSON for example.

### Version 2: Storing only the ID's of the selected items

```
class MainView {
  SelectedCountryID: number;
  SelectedCityID: number;

  SelectionInfo: string; // computed, should return the "You've selected ...." caption

  Countries: List<RegionModel>; // datasource for country select
  Cities: List<RegionModel> // datasource for city select
}
```

**Pros:**

- It's efficient in the way that it contains only the information which
  is most likely needed by consumer APIs.
- No additional conversion is needed, and efficiently can be passed
  nearly "as is" to a server-side or other API.

**Cons:**

- Not so straightforward and readable (in my opinion).
- What about computing the info string? That's now much harder, I need
  to grab the needed members from the selection source lists with a
  search by the given ID, so it depends heavily on the consistency of
  those lists (I mean the item must be present there).

I hope it won't be closed quickly as unconstructive. Any kind of advices, thoughts or experiences will be appreciated. Also, if the answer is "it depends", please try to give my some points where and when to use which.

UPDATE

I think my question was a bit unclear. I know about decoupling viewmodel from database entities, here I never mentioned database entities. I mentioned an "abstract consumer API". In a concrete scenario: if the API needs the selected items' Names, and my API needs only the IDs, which alternative should I choose, and where should do the conversion?

For example my server expects a data format like this (JSON):

```
{
  "SelectedCountryID": 2,
  "SelectedCityID": 5
}
```

and nothing else. How could I handle it in an elegant way? I would like to avoid repeating myself by doing a manual conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how your *datasources* are implemented, it may make not difference: if you are retrieving the list of countries and cities, you can either store a reference to the selected value, to one of its fields or its index in the list.

Disregarding that, you should decouple your view model entities from your database entities and put into your view model ones only those fields required by the views. This way, your information traffic is minimized and your code is less affected by changes in the database.

**EDIT** following OP's update:

Talking about interacting with an API instead of a database, I think you can apply the same ideas, just replacing "database entities" by "service layer entities" (for instance, the JSON coming in/out your server). Take the returned data that into your view model objects, holding those attributes that you need. Obviously you also may need to store an `id` as you stated, when you'll need to refer to the same entity later on.

From a theoretical point of view, you should not include any other fields not consumed by the view, but you could do so depending on your requirements. For instance, in cases when you'll need to pass those fields back to the service layer and you don't want to query again by `id` to retrieve the service entity. However there are other alternatives to this  (for example, some kind of cache), the exact balance depends on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the addtions. I think I'm trying to think too much. I have a feeling that I'm tring to vilolate something that I shouldn't. I see that I would like to use the same representation as viewmodel and as a service DTO, which seems to not work in this case. And you're right, in this case the API model acts like a database entity. I think I'll accept your answer because this made me thinking that I most likely use a bad design. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Base on MVVM pattern your viewModel should be an object with all properties which you need to display in view. ViewModel should be only used to be strictly binded to the view. Anyway your example it's not very good in my opinion. You shouldn't think about viewModel in case of storing something, please think more about presenting data.

Please remember that before you have data in database you have to insert it. So if you have some form with First Name and Last Name, user at first must fill this form and data must be insert into database, without it you don't have any ID.

To summarize in my opinion viewModel should have properties which you have to present to the end-user.

Comment: Yes I get it, "storing" was an unfortunate word usage from me. Here the presentation is not effected by each of the two versions. Usually binding to a select box gives you the chance to bind the selected item as object (version 1), or use its id only (version 2), the user will see the same.

Comment: But your example is focused on drop down list where that's true that you've got key and value, but what about other form elements like text boxes, radio buttons etc. But if you have viewModel which has for example: FirstName, LastName, City (binded to drop down list) and you only wondering if City should be a complex object (with key and value properties) or plain property (just int for key or string for value), my answer would it depend. If you need to manipulate with value in server side it's better to have complex object, if not it's ok to use only ID for this one.

Comment: Yes, I meant something like that. With textboxes or other simple inputs the question is much more simple. If the consumer AOI needs only keys, but my view needs the selected items' texts as well, how should I handle it? I've updated my question to clarify this.

Comment: Ok, now that's clear. I prefer to use complex objects for that consisting of Id and Description or enums if this is a short constance collection. I prefer that because I have more options to manipulate with that object in server side, not only save or update. Various frameworks, languages support in different way binding to the drop down lists (select tag). What's more if you need to generate dynamically dropdown list in view you can't do this base only on id, but if you have collection of complex objects (id, value) it's not a problem.

Comment: What you can do either is to have collection of complex objects to display drop down and other property like 'selectedItemKey'.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, my problem was not actually with collections for the select boxes, but with representing the currently selected item (as complex or as "key"). But now I feel that my design seems to be basically wrong in that manner that I'm trying to use the same model as DTO and viewmodel as well, and in this case those are (and should be) different I guess.